# how to Automatically open the url that is scan from the qr code?

Tags: android

im creating an android app to scan qr code and redirect into that url automatically.
now i have an app which scans the qr code and displays a pop up of the url with a "visit" button..when clicked will redirect me to that url .But i want to skip that pop up process and let me scan the qr code and automatically goes to that url without any pop up in between.
what modification should i do . please say in simple terms since i dont know much coding.

this is the code for handling the result

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String myResult = result.getText();
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myResult));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
    alert1.show();
}
```

}

Comment: "*i want to skip that pop up process and let me scan the qr code and automatically goes to that url*", and deny the user the possibility to evaluate whether the URL is not a malware file that will be executed automatically? Such application won't be allowed in a business environment.

Answer (score 3):

Remove alert dialog code and call your intent directly inside method.

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String myResult = result.getText();
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myResult));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```